# Setting a mask in Python with Moviepy

Tags: python, mask, transparent, moviepy

I wanted to mask a video, to get rid of some pixel errors. The mask itself is an image (png). I tried several options to applie the mask to my video, but it doesn't work so far (see pictures).

The mask image is an png with alpha values. I want to darken several regions of the pixel errors video. The rest of the video should not see an impact of the mask/image.
My mask image is working on single images of the movie, but not for the whole movie.

```
clip=VideoFileClip(File)
maskclip=ImageClip("Maskimage.png",ismask=True,transparent=True)
clip.set_mask(maskclip)
clip.write_videofile("masked.mp4",codec=libx264)
```

I have no idea, why the mask is not working. There is no error of the compiler.

[Picture with pixel errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DI7VC.png)
[Picture with masked pixel errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gthb4.png)

Comment: You need to set the duration on the ImageClip, else it is going to apply only to the first frame of the video.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have used the mask and see it instructed:

```
        clip = clip.copy()
        clip = clip.add_mask()
        clip.mask.duration = clip.duration
```